# How to parse json (feed) from PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a json feed from zoho : [here](http://creatorexport.zoho.com/marcandremenard/application-lemieux/json/Liste_produits_View1/DmwJ5O8VEZA5MhN5MbbCt7D4SW6neX5bOUECqGeXsDg5pe5sT0VRvt54q35fQGTh0By73mWanrvQUhwgt59VPNet9TgzWnyRpmb6/), you can acces the same file unencrypted [here](http://produits-lemieux.com/json.txt)
I like to be able to display and parse the data from that feed int html

I have ask a similar question yesterday, but the solution was a javascript, and having java disable client side can lead to nothing to display... so i will go with php. I can parse a var but a feed ?....

Question #2. Is it possible to capture a json feed, and save it as file (for backup purpose), so i will acces that file if the site go down (small possibilites)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You first have to get the JSON data from the remote server ; not sure how you can do that, considering there seems to be an authentication mecanism in place, but maybe [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) or [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) could help.

Once you have that JSON string in a PHP variable, it's just a matter of calling [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) on it, to get your data.

For instance :

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://produits-lemieux.com/json.txt');

// you can save $json to a file, if needed :
//file_put_contents('file/path/my-file.txt', $json);

$data = json_decode($json);

var_dump($data);
```

Will get you an output like this one :

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'Liste_des_produits1' => 
    array
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'Added_Time' => string '28-Sep-2009 16:35:03' (length=20)
          public 'prod_ingredient' => string 'sgsdgds' (length=7)
          public 'prod_danger' => 
            array
              0 => string 'sans danger pour xyz' (length=20)
    ....
```

Note I used the "not encrypted" version, because I have no idea what kind of API you need to use to access the crypted one *(never used "zoho")*

Comment: any way to display it a nicer way (to be able to reed it )

Comment: To display it to read it... Heu... for debugging purposes ? var_dump, with the http://xdebug.org/ extension installed, is perfect ;-) (and that extension is really nice, on a development machine -- don't install it on a production server, though : not good for performances)

Comment: maybe a method to acces the variable ? i will show it my way !...
i have try something like : print_r($result.Liste_des_produits1.prod_ingredient);

Comment: Je peut peut etre te poser quelques autres questions par email perso (menardmam@hotmail.com) si tu veut ?

Comment: print_r($data->Liste_des_produits1[0]->prod_ingredient;

Comment: @marc-andre : I would rather prefer not, please

Answer (score 2):

json_decode will convert the json string to object form by default, in order to use it as associative array you have to specify 'true' as second parameter, example below.
    json_decode($json,true)

reference : [php Json_decode reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

The simplified code to do what you want.

```
$sJson = file_get_contents('http://example.com/path/to/feed.json');
file_put_contents('/path/to/file', $sJson);
$oJson = json_decode($sJson);   
var_dump($oJson);
```

If URL Wrappers are off or you need authentication headers (or other special headers set), use the [curl](http://php.net/curl) libraries in place of `file_get_contents`.

Comment: perfect solution. just as the one above... 4 minutes later... but thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I like to be able to print/access some variable but cannot seem to have the trick to access the array the wright way

based on the previous answer :

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://produits-lemieux.com/json.txt');
$data = json_decode($json);
//var_dump($data);
print_r($data['prod_ingredient']); //dont work !... error 
print_r($data['Liste_des_produits1'].prod_ingredient[0]); //dont work !... error
```